# Thread Handling after exception

Tags: java, multithreading, performance

used `thread.sleep` when exception occurs in my application 
 if any thing exception occured in any one of the thread it should wait for some time and have to try again

what i am facing the issue means for 100 request if exception occurs for 50 means that should be wait for some time and after try again if any
 exception occurs means it should also wait till success

am feeling this going to affect the performance and system usage.

Please let me know your suggestions. Is it better to create new thread if any exception occurs?
Or Any other way?

Comment: why do you expect so much exceptional cases ? may be you can fine tune app to minimize exceptional conditions, with this scenario in short period of time you would have too many RUNNABLE threads

Comment: ya thats fine. but for particular exception how do we handle threads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the question, I understand that, you are talking about `RunTimeExceptions`.

1) Firstly I would like to suggest that, you should examine the code areas which may really throw the exceptions at run time i.e processing of files.

2) another thing is that you have to handle this scenarios so that exception cases are reduced. i.e first check file is available then only try to read it, check permissions before writing it etc. In this way frequency of retrying may be reduced.
3) If both above actions fails, means the situation which can never be handled such as services are down etc., you can retry the considering all necessary aspects like - MAX try, MAX time out foe which you are re-trying, leave the attempt after certain amount of try OR time etc.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is it possible to do in any other way?

Comment: No. Everything seems to be covered in these 3 options.

Answer (score 2):

Retrying on exception isn't a bad idea, but you should make sure that:

1. The exception is transient (i.e. you have reasons to believe it may
   succeed on retry, like a network error)
2. You have ways to prevent retrying forever (like "max retry")
3. You don't overload the system by too frequent retries by e.g. using exponential back-off strategy (or even just a reasonably long wait time)

Exception to rule 2 is possible (sometimes you do want stuff to retry forever).